# How to drag and drop a video?

Tags: android, video, drag-and-drop

I am writing an application in which I want to show a video coming from a server. The video is displayed correctly through a VideoView. The video doesn't take up all space, it's actually a little square on the bottom left. Now I want to add the capacity to this video to be dragged and dropped. While it's being dragged, I want the video to keep playing fluently. How do you do that ?

Comment: Theoretically I think you could do it the same as any other view ([drag and drop API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html)). But I doubt that you will be able to get the device to play the video fluently while it is also listening for and reacting to touch events by moving the Video, I think you are asking too much of the hardware for most of the devices in existence today. That being said, this is only a hunch, I may be wrong. HARDWARE_ACCELERATED would probably help.

Comment: I thought of that but the drag and drop API is only available on API 11. I am looking for something compatible with older version (At least 2.2).

Comment: You can use an `onTouchListener` to implement your own drag and drop on API prior to 11. [This article](http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/04/simple-drag-n-drop-on-android.html) shows an example and links to the source code for it. It could be adapted to do what you want. Though I think you are unlikely to find a device running something older than API 11 that is going to have the muscle to pull it off and make it look nice.